# To show a family of holomorphic function on unit disc satisfying $|f(0)|^2+\int_D|f'(z)|^2dA\leq1$ is normal

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My attempt was to show, 
$|f(z)|^2<|f(0)|^2+|f(z)-f(0)|^2\leq|f(0)|^2+(\int_\gamma|f'(z)|)^2$, where $\gamma$ is any rectifiable path connecting 0 to $z$. But now it is a line integral, not the integral over a disc is involved.

Could you tell how to apply the condition given? Or is my approach wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon >0$ It is enough to show that the family is uniformly bounded on $\{z:|z|\leq 1-\epsilon\}$. Let $|z|\leq 1-\epsilon$. Consider the disk $D_{\epsilon}$ of radius $\epsilon /2$ around $z$. It is well known that analytic functions have mean value property so $f'(z)$ is the average of its values on $D_{\epsilon}$. Using the hypothesis and Cauchy -Schwarz inequality we get an upper bound for $|f'(z)|$ on $D_{\epsilon}$. Since $|f(0)| \leq 1$ and $f(z)$ is $f(0)$ plus the integral of $f'$  on the line segment from $0$ to $z$ we have proved that the family is uniformly bounded on $D_{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Where is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality being used?

Comment: $|\int_{D_{\epsilon}} f'(z)\, dm(z)| \leq (\int_{D_{\epsilon}} |f'(z)|^{2} \, dm(z)|)^{1/2} (m(D_{\epsilon})^{1/2}$ where $m$ is two dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that mean value property can be used to describe harmonic functions only. I did not notice that it can also be used to describe holomorphic functions.  I would like to ask further that if $|f|^2$ harmonic since it has mean value property.

Comment: $|f(z)|^{2}$ need not be  harmonic. If $f(z)=z$ then the Laplacian of $|f(z)|^{2}$ is 4.